# Как передать в отправку формы заявки выбранные значения мультиселекта?

Tags: javascript, html, html-form, html-select

Вот форма заявки: https://vezdehod-techsnab.ru/new/dt-30-p-vityaz.html#orderSpareParts

Мультиселект (https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen).

Форма почему-то отправляет только первое значение из ряда выбранных в мультиселекте.
Как это исправить и отправлять все выбранные позиции списка.

```html
<form method="post" id="orderForm" action="mtlbu-spare-parts-order-complete.php">
    <input name="fullname" value="" type="text" required="" placeholder="Укажите имя и фамилию" maxlength="255" class="fullname">
    <input name="phone" value="" type="tel" required="" placeholder="Контактный телефон" maxlength="16" pattern="\+7\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}" class="phone">
    <input name="email" value="" type="email" required="" placeholder="Эл. почта" maxlength="255" class="email">
    <input name="location" value="" type="text" placeholder="Адрес доставки" maxlength="255" class="location">
    <div id="test_me_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-multi multiselect">
    <select data-placeholder="Выберите запчасти ДТ30 П «Витязь» для заказа" multiple class="chzn-select" id="test_me" name="select" tabindex="8" required="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>100.01.000 Установка двигателя</option>
        <option>21.01.0112 Болт установочный</option>
        <option>100.01.002-01 Прокладка регулировочная</option>
        <option>100.01.002 Прокладка регулировочная</option>
        <option>100.01.001 Прокладка регулировочная</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <textarea name="text" class="input input_textarea" placeholder="Текст сообщения" title="Напишите вашу заявку" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить заявку" id="sendButton" class="btn">
    <script src="js/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chosen.js"></script>
    <script> $$(".chzn-select").chosen(); $$(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true}); </script>     
</form>
```

```
    <?php
    $fullname = trim( $_POST['fullname']);
    $email = trim( $_POST['email']);    
    $phone = trim( $_POST['phone']); 
    $location = trim( $_POST['location']); 
    $select = trim($_POST['select']);               
    $text = trim( $_POST['text']);      


    $fromMail = 'admin@vezdehod-techsnab.ru';
    $fromName = 'Заказ запчастей для ДТ30 П «Витязь»';

    $emailTo = 'egorpolyakov@list.ru';
    $subject = 'Заявка из каталога «ТехГазСнаб»';
    $subject = '=?utf-8?b?'. base64_encode($subject) .'?=';
    $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ". $fromName ." <". $fromMail ."> \r\n";

    $body = "Заявка из каталога «ТехГазСнаб»\n\nИмя клиента: $fullname\n\nЭл.почта: $email\n\nТелефон: $phone\n\nАдрес доставки: $location\n\nЗапчасти для ДТ30 П «Витязь»: $select\n\nСообщение: $text\n\n";


    if (strlen($email) > 0) {
        $mail = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f'. $fromMail );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Она передаёт все значения. Вы обрабатываете одно. Можно завести переменную, в которую записать все значения `$_POST['select']` и работать как с массивом. Так же у `option` должно быть `value`, по которому вы будете заполнять нужные значения

Comment: Вы можете показать рабочий пример для понимания?